# Cannot fix pm2 syslog error - pm2-root.service: Can't open PID file /root/.pm2/pm2.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

I found following error on our debian 10 server, where I run react + express js app.
The auto-restart occurs every minute.
I have tried to update pm2 to the latest version, which helped someone else but I haven't succeeded.
I'd appreciate any tips or advice.

```
pm2-root.service: Can't open PID file /root/.pm2/pm2.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Dec  3 15:42:45 polaris-dev kernel: [85973.238434] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens192 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:5c:49:79:68:e8:97:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:5e49:79ff:fe68:e897 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=255 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=53805 DPT=53805 LEN=24 
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev systemd[1]: pm2-root.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev systemd[1]: pm2-root.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev systemd[1]: Failed to start PM2 process manager.
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev systemd[1]: pm2-root.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev systemd[1]: pm2-root.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 950.
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev systemd[1]: Stopped PM2 process manager.
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev systemd[1]: Starting PM2 process manager...
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: [PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/root/.pm2
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'cat' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'cd' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'chmod' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'cp' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'dirs' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'pushd' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'popd' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'echo' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'tempdir' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'pwd' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'exec' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'ls' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'find' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'grep' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'head' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'ln' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'mkdir' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'rm' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'mv' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'sed' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'set' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'sort' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'tail' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'test' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'to' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'toEnd' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'touch' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'uniq' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: (node:21298) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'which' of module exports inside circular dependency
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: [PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: [PM2] Resurrecting
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: [PM2] Restoring processes located in /root/.pm2/dump.pm2
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: [PM2] Process /opt/tessa5g/server.js restored
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: ┌─────┬───────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: │ id  │ name      │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: ├─────┼───────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: │ 0   │ server    │ default     │ N/A     │ fork    │ N/A      │ 0      │ 0    │ errored   │ 0%       │ 0b       │ root     │ disabled │
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev pm2[21298]: └─────┴───────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
Dec  3 15:42:53 polaris-dev systemd[1]: pm2-root.service: Can't open PID file /root/.pm2/pm2.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
```